# A short javascript to keep scrolling to the top of page until the end?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, http, web

I'm using web interface of telegram (a IM like whatsapp) so I want to view some message which is on top of page and I want to scroll but there are like 15000 lines and i dont want to keep pressing pageup so is there a java script which i could execute in console to reach to the top??

Comment: Your questions asks how to scroll to the top within your interface but you also ask how to do so in the console.  It would be useful to clarify what you expect or better yet, read up on How to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: not my interface,an already established website and for that according to my understanding to have to execute a command through browser interface?

Answer (score 0):

To scroll to the top of an element in JavaScript you can use vanilla JavaScript and the Web API:

```
yourElement.scrollTop = 0;
```

You can read more about this function on the [MDN docs: Element.scrollTop()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollTop).

Comment: thanks for reply dear sir...and just being a total newbie to javascript can you guide me to how to find the name of element??

Comment: It's easier if you update your question to include the HTML _and_ the JavaScript that you attempted.  USer's on SO like to see the effort put in by a poster and are then more likely to offer assistance.

Comment: I'm not making  a web page or something.The web page already exits.I'm asking for a **javascript which I can run in chrome's console** like there existed some for clicking on all like buttons and so

Answer (score 0):

Just run the following in browser console:

```
window.scrollTo(0,0);
```

```css
div {
height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<div>
scroll down to see the button
</div>
<button onclick="window.scrollTo(0,0)">scroll to Top</button>
```

Comment: @DellOmni Hmm. Should have worked if you have run in the console window and if there was scrolling required to go to top. Any ways good luck.